# How to know which element was clicked

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, classname

I have this code:

```
( function() {
  var i, ii, e = Elements.Select('.drop');
  for ( i = 0, ii = e.length; i < ii; i++ ) {
    e [ i ].onclick = function () {
      alert ( e [ i ].getAttribute('data-open') );
    }
  }
})();
```

What I do is that when clicking an element with the className 'drop', then alert the attribute of the element I was clicking. But doesn't work's.

this piece of code is the one I use to select an element by her className.
Don't pay much attention, its only to show us is just to show them how I select the elements.

```
(function() {
  Select : function ( element ) { 
  var object, index  = element.substr( 0, 1 ), name = element.substr( 1, element.length ),      clases = [ ], i, all = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"); 
  switch ( index ) { 
    case '.' : 
      for ( i = 0; i < all.length; i ++ ) { 
        if ( all [ i ].className == name ) {   
          clases.push( all [ i ] ); 
        } 
      } 
      object = clases; 
    break;  
    return object 
    } 
  } 
})();
```

¿Answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( function() {
  var i, ii, e = Elements.Select('.drop');
  for ( i = 0, ii = e.length; i < ii; i++ ) {
    e [ i ].onclick = function () {
      //by the time that this gets executed, the for loop is ended, thus i equals ii
      // instead of using e[i]... try using this : 
      alert (this.getAttribute('data-open'));
      alert ( e [ i ].getAttribute('data-open') );
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery for this.Here, the 'this' keyword gives you the current element which was clicked. This function is fired on the click event of any element whose class name is 'drop'.

```
$(".drop").click( function(){
   var x=$(this).attr("data-open");
});
```

Comment: Can you help me withot JQuery?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that my method of doing this in Javascript will work, but will try to give you a solution using just that too..

Comment: The above code won't run even with jQuery. Either use POJS `this.getAttribute('data-open')` or with jQuery `$(this).attr('data-open')`